# How to return HTML string from ReactJs for Javascript/jQuery manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

```
var MyBox = React.createClass({
    rawMarkup: function() {
        var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
        return { __html: rawMarkup };
    },
    getElements: function () {
        //I want to be able to return raw HTML string
        //from here to inject into another element via jQuery
    },
    loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: []};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.loadCommentsFromServer();
        window.drill = this;
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li>item1</li>
                <li>item2</li>
                <li>item3</li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
});
```

via Javascript using jQuery I want to inject the output to another element like below

```
  $(clicked).html(window.drill.getElements());
```

Comment: Your `window.this` is the react component, not the actual HTML.
Give your component an `id`, then you can simply read it from the DOM using jQuery.

Comment: Yup I am reading it via window.drill.getElements(). I hope you can give me a code sample. I am not familiar with component having IDs

Comment: Oh I get it. <ul> element should have id then read in from the DOM and I will take care of the data via this.state.data right?

Comment: My problem will be the rendering of the elements new values base on what the user's clicked. Those clickable items are not generated by ReactJs. Just a Bootstrap accordion/Panel rendered via AngularJs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid having two owners/ updaters of the same component. You should really choose between:

A. make your react code the owner of *all* HTML inside the component.
 B. do not use react to render the code, but let Angular/ BootstrapJS or whatever manipulate the DOM.

If you go with A, then change your react code to:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    // You do not need the window.drill = this here
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <ul id='foo'>
            <li>item1</li>
            <li>item2</li>
            <li>item3</li>
        </ul>
    );
}
```

And then have your code read the contents of the DOM by through javascript `getElementByID('foo')` of jQuery `$('#foo')`, which you can copy to somewhere else.

If you want to update the contents of the component based on what user clicks, your react component needs a listener to changes somewhere else (*in your model, not in the DOM*), and re-render the component with new props.
Then when the user clicks something, the onClick code should update model, which triggers re-render.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yup make sense. This is a great help. I could still use window.drill = this to trigger the listener and let React handle the output. And jquery for DOM manipulation just like you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: The reason for such is because the data source location will come from Angular output which I can pass to React Listener to fetch the said data.Thanks.